# Windows Azure Set Up Walkthrough (Dummy's guide preferably)?

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure

I'm thinking about moving one of my projects onto Windows Azure - But was wondering if any super talented developers have written a guide on how to configure / set it up and then deploy a site?

I have seen a couple of videos for people doing it on EC2 but wanted to do it on Azure...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maarten Balliauw has [a great series of articles](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/07/02/How-we-built-TwitterMaticnet-Part-1-Introduction.aspx) on building a Twitter client app in the cloud using the Azure platform.

Well worth a read.

Kindness,

Dan